# Programmatically changing file type from XLSX to CSV

Tags: php, oracle, csv, phpexcel

Using PHP Excel, I am programmatically attempting to convert `.xlsx` files to `.csv`. My code takes user-uploaded spreadsheets, saved as either `xlsx`, `csv`, `xls` and uploads them to an Oracle 11g Database. The code currently works with `xls` and `csv` (at least most of the time). When I upload a `.xlsx` file, why do I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' 
with message 'The filename /tmp/phpsu3acF is not recognised as an OLE file' 
in /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/JointUse/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php:89 

Stack trace: 
#0 /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/JointUse/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php(1164): PHPExcel_Shared_OLERead->read('/tmp/phpsu3acF') 
#1 /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/JointUse/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php(612): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5->_loadOLE('/tmp/phpsu3acF') 
#2 /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/JointUse/update_handler.php(21): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5->load('/tmp/phpsu3acF') 
#3 {main} thrown in /opt/apache/servers/planninganddesign/htdocs/JointUse/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php on line 89
```

Form:

```
   <?php require('reader.php');

    ini_set("memory_limit","200M");
     ?>


    <form name="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="update_handler.php" method="post" >

       <b>Accepted File Extensions: .csv .xls </b><br>
       Please save your excel table as one of the <br>accepted file extensions prior to uploading. <br><br>
       <u>Upload File:</u> <input type="file" name="uploaded"><br>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

Handler:

```
<?php
require_once('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'); 
require_once("mcl_Oci.php");
?>

<br>

<?php

    $filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
    $file = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($ext='xls') {



        $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
        $inputFileName = $file;

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

        $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

        foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
                $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
                $objWriter->save('abc.csv');}
        $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r'); 
        if($files) {
                while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
            }       echo 'Your .xls file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';
        } elseif($ext='csv'){
            while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
            }   echo 'Your .csv file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';
        } elseif($ext='xlsx') {
            while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
            }   echo 'Your .xlsx file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';     
        }

        else {
            echo "This is not an accepted file type. Please save as either '*.csv' or '*.xls' and re-upload.";
        }
    }


    $ArrayNumber = 3;   

    while ($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"] != NULL) {
    $ArrayNumber = $ArrayNumber + 1;
    $RECEIVED = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["1"], "'\"");
    $REGION = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["2"], "'\"");
    $PERMIT = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["3"], "'\"");
    $CUSTOMER = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["4"], "'\"");
    $TO_BUSINESS = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["5"], "'\"");
    $TO_PERMIT = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["6"], "'\"");
    $POWER_ADDRESS = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["7"], "'\"");
    $COMPANY = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["8"], "'\"");
    $MAPSECTION = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["9"], "'\"");
    $LOCATION = trim($csv_array["ArrayNumber"]["10"], "'\"");
    $POLES = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["11"], "'\"");
    $FEE = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["12"], "'\"");
    $INVOICE = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["13"], "'\"");
    $DATE_LARRY = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["14"], "'\"");
    $DAYS_LARRY = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["15"], "'\"");
    $PI_PON = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["16"], "'\"");
    $DATE_PD = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["17"], "'\"");
    $DAYS_LARRY_PD = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["18"], "'\"");
    $RETURNED = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["19"], "'\"");
    $DAYS_PD = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["20"], "'\"");
    $ERRORS_PD = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["21"], "'\"");
    $ERRORS_MULTIPLE = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["22"], "'\"");
    $DATE_MAKEREADY_JU = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["23"], "'\"");
    $DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["24"], "'\"");
    $DAYS_MAKEREADY = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["25"], "'\"");
    $APPROVAL = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["26"], "'\"");
    $DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["27"], "'\"");
    $DATE_PLANNING = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["28"], "'\"");
    $DAYS_OPEN = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["29"], "'\"");
    $DATE_ROUTED = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["30"], "'\"");
    $DAYS_TOTAL = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["31"], "'\"");
    $COMMENTS = trim($csv_array["$ArrayNumber"]["32"], "'\"");



    $check = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF FROM INTOXDM.JOINT_USE WHERE PERMIT = '$PERMIT'";
    $checkparse = oci_parse($objConnect,$check);
    oci_define_by_name($checkparse, 'NUMBER_OF', $CHECK);
    oci_execute($checkparse);
    oci_fetch($checkparse);

    if ($CHECK == 0) {

        $objConnect = oci_connect("user", "pass", "(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=HOST)(port=1533))(connect_data=(service_name=sid)))");
        $strSQL =  "INSERT INTO INTOXDM.JOINT_USE (RECEIVED, REGION, PERMIT, CUSTOMER, TO_BUSINESS, TO_PERMIT, POWER_ADDRESS, COMPANY, MAPSECTION, POLES, FEE, INVOICE, DATE_LARRY, DAYS_LARRY, PI_PON, DATE_PD, DAYS_LARRY_PD, RETURNED, DAYS_PD, ERRORS_PD, ERRORS_MULTIPLE, DATE_MAKEREADY_JU, DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE, DAYS_MAKEREADY, APPROVAL, DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU, DATE_PLANNING, DAYS_OPEN, DATE_ROUTED, DAYS_TOTAL, COMMENTS) VALUES ('$RECEIVED', '$REGION', '$PERMIT', '$CUSTOMER', '$TO_BUSINESS', '$TO_PERMIT', '$POWER_ADDRESS', '$COMPANY', '$MAPSECTION', '$POLES', '$FEE', '$INVOICE', '$DATE_LARRY', '$DAYS_LARRY', '$PI_PON', '$DATE_PD', '$DAYS_LARRY_PD', '$RETURNED', '$DAYS_PD', '$ERRORS_PD', '$ERRORS_MULTIPLE', '$DATE_MAKEREADY_JU', '$DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE', '$DAYS_MAKEREADY', '$APPROVAL', '$DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU', '$DATE_PLANNING', '$DAYS_OPEN', '$DATE_ROUTED', '$DAYS_TOTAL', '$COMMENTS')";
        $parse = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL);
        $execute = oci_execute(oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL));
    } else { 


        $strSQL =  "UPDATE INTOXDM.JOINT_USE SET RECEIVED = '$RECEIVED', REGION = '$REGION', CUSTOMER = '$CUSTOMER', TO_BUSINESS = '$TO_BUSINESS', TO_PERMIT = '$TO_PERMIT', POWER_ADDRESS = '$POWER_ADDRESS', COMPANY = '$COMPANY', MAPSECTION = '$MAPSECTION', POLES = '$POLES', FEE = '$FEE', INVOICE = '$INVOICE', DATE_LARRY = '$DATE_LARRY', DAYS_LARRY = '$DAYS_LARRY', PI_PON = '$PI_PON', DATE_PD = '$DATE_PD', DAYS_LARRY_PD = '$DAYS_LARRY_PD', RETURNED = '$RETURNED', DAYS_PD = '$DAYS_PD', ERRORS_PD = '$ERRORS_PD', ERRORS_MULTIPLE = '$ERRORS_MULTIPLE', DATE_MAKEREADY_JU = '$DATE_MAKEREADY_JU', DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE = '$DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPELTE', DAYS_MAKEREADY = '$DAYS_MAKEREADY', APPROVAL = '$APPROVAL', DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU = '$DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU', DATE_PLANNING = '$DATE_PLANNING', DAYS_OPEN = '$DAYS_OPEN', DATE_ROUTED = '$DATE_ROUTED', DAYS_TOTAL = '$DAYS_TOTAL', COMMENTS = '$COMMENTS' WHERE PERMIT = '$PERMIT'";
        $parse = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL);
        $execute = oci_execute($parse); }


    $DELETE = "DELETE FROM INTOXDM.JOINT_USE WHERE PERMIT IS NULL";
    $parseDelete = oci_parse($objConnect, $DELETE);
    $execute = oci_execute($parseDelete);
    }

    $conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=HOST)(port=1533))(connect_data=(service_name=sid)))");
    $sel = "update INTOXDM.JOINT_USE set DAYS = trunc(sysdate - to_date(RECEIVED, 'MM/DD/YY'))";
    $par = oci_parse($conn, $sel);
    $exe = oci_execute($par);

header("location: website"); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `Excel5` Reader for (`OfficeOpenXML`) `.xlsx` files: the `Excel5` Reader is for `BIFF`-format `.xls` files; you need to use the `Excel2007` Reader for `OfficeOpenXML`-format files.

If your users can upload files in different formats; either use the IOFactory `identify()` method to tell you which Reader to use, then instantiate that Reader; or simply use the IOFactory `load()` method which will automatically select the correct Reader.

Comment: Where can I find the `Excel2007` reader? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';` - that's why I write documentation for PHPExcel.... there's a whole document explaining the different spreadsheet file formats and the appropriate Readers called `PHPExcel User Documentation - Reading Spreadsheet Files` in the `/Documentation` folder for PHPExcel

Comment: Oh okay, I completely misunderstood your answer. Now I get it haha! So, upon using the `load()` method, it will select the reader? From there I can put all contents into an array to use?

Comment: Using IOFactory load(), PHPExcel will determine the filetype, select the correct Reader and load the file into a PHPExcel object using that Reader

Comment: What I'm unsure about is why you need to save the file as CSV, then reload it again; why not access the data for your merge directly from the PHPExcel object?

Comment: I didn't realize this was possible when I rolled out v1 of my program. Since I've posted this question, I've altered my code to do what you stated. What I read on line seemed to tell me that the only way for me to make this work was to convert it to a CSV, which I just recently learned is definitely not the case.